# Flutter StatelessWidget and Provider not updating or calling build unnecessarily

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I'm trying to use `Provider` with a `Stateless` widget page to update a countdown UI.

When I run all the below, I get both print messages in the console on each 1 second tick of the stopwatch:

e.g.

```
flutter: build()
flutter: _buildCountDown()
```

Also, the `remaining` value doesn't actually update in the UI.

**But if I:**

- make the page a `StatefulWidget`
- replace the variable access with `Consumer<CountdownProvider>` syntax e.g.

```
return Consumer<CountdownProvider>(
  builder: (_, countdownProvider, __) {
    return Text(countdownProvider.remaining.toString()),
});
```

...everything works as expected: the UI updates properly and I don't get the `build()` printout, just the `_buildCountDown()`, which is what I wanted.

**Q) What am I doing wrong that means I can't make this a Stateless widget that updates as expected?**

---

1. main.dart I have the Provider like so:

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [        
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => CountdownProvider(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

2. I have written a simple countdown provider - `CountdownProvider`:

```
class CountdownProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  int remaining = 0;
  final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  late Timer _timer;

  void start(int val) {
    remaining = val;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), _onTick);
    _stopwatch.start();
  }

  void _onTick(Timer timer) {
    remaining--;
    if (remaining < 0) {
      return;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stop(bool skipNotify) {
    _timer.cancel();
    _stopwatch.stop();

    if (skipNotify) {
      _stopwatch.reset();
      remaining = 0;
      return;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

3. Page to display it: `PageCountdown`:

```
class PageCountdown extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageCountdown({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // 10 seconds default countdown
    Provider.of<CountdownProvider>(context, listen: false).start(10);

    print("build()");
    return Scaffold(
      body: _buildContent(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          _buildCountDown(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCountDown(BuildContext context) {
    int remaining = Provider.of<CountdownProvider>(context).remaining;

    print("_buildCountDown()");

    return Text(
      remaining.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageCountdown` is the single widget, which is rebuilt when the counter ticks. `start(10)` in the beginning of `build` will reset `remaining` to 10 every rebuild. Something like this will work:

```
class PageCountdown extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageCountdown({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // 10 seconds default countdown
    Provider.of<CountdownProvider>(context, listen: false).start(10);

    print("build()");
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Countdown(),
    );
  }
}

class Countdown extends StatelessWidget {
  const Countdown({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          _buildCountDown(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCountDown(BuildContext context) {
    int remaining = Provider.of<CountdownProvider>(context).remaining;

    print("_buildCountDown()");

    return Text(
      remaining.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so are you effectively saying that the only way to use the syntax without Consumer is to split widget builds into separate classes always?

Comment: That's one way to do it, as long as there is a different context.